# Google SERP: example.com vs. www.example.com vs https://example.com

Tags: seo

I am aware that I can use Google Webmaster Tools to select wether my sites should be shown or without a leading `WWW`.

However, I noticed recently that some pages show the protocol while some others don't, for example on this SERP:

[image]

At first I thought that the protocol is only shown for sites that support SSL (so it would be `https://`), but I noticed that this is not always the case, because when I click on the first link in the following picture, I am actually taken to a site with SSL:

[image]

Comment: Some sites respond to both where HTTPS would be required for some portions of the website such as login, payments, etc. This would not necessarily create a duplicate content scenario if canonical links are used. I would assume that in the SERPs you are seeing HTTPS because perhaps these sites redirect from HTTP to HTTPS and only server content on HTTPS. Just a guess.

Comment: I too only seem to see `https://` links in the SERPs for _all links_ that are indeed `https://`. If it doesn't show `https` then it's not `https` from my tests. In your last example... If I do the same search I see the same result (although in English) but for me this goes to the non-SSL URL `http://`, whether I'm logged into SO or not (incognito mode). What does the link report if you hover over it? Is it possible the redirection is occurring _after_ you click the link?

Comment: Ah, yes, you are right. I also only get redirected to SSL when I'm logged in to SO. So it seems that for sites that are indexed with SSL, the protocol is shown, and for all other sites the protocol is not shown. If you want you can add your comment as an answer so I can accept it... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only sites that are indexed with encryption show the `https` protocol.   Google always hides the protocol when it is `http`.

StackOverflow is generally indexed with `http` which is why the protocol is hidden.   I'm not sure why you are getting to the secure site from Google.   You may have a browser extension such as [HTTPS Everywhere](https://www.eff.org/https-everywhere) installed that is causing that.

Comment: I do have HTTPS Everywhere installed and your answer completely corresponds with my findings in this area. My personal opinion is that search results without the protocol look much cleaner, and I feel that I am almost being penaltized by Google for using SSL encryption. Oh well. :)

Comment: Google's Chromium is already talking about [warning on HTTP](https://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/marking-http-as-non-secure) instead of the other way around, so I'm sure search results will switch too in the (relatively) near future.

Comment: Clearly Google thinks that showing the `https` is important for users.   Hopefully they have done testing that shows that it entices users to cilck instead of turning them away.   Maybe they could start noting that in the SERPs with a secure lock icon that would be less geeky.